# List index out of range using re

Tags: python, python-re

While running my program, the program will randomly crash and displayer Error: List index out of range. however, I'm only looking to index the only number in the list. I don't understand why after a certain amount of time this number would cease to exist.

```py
etherPrice = str(cryptocompare.get_price('ETH', currency='USD'))
intRegex2 = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+')
result2 = intRegex2.findall(etherPrice)
resultString2 = str(result2[0])
```

Comment: The pattern `\d+\.\d+` has a mandatory decimal part. You can make that optional `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` and before indexing, check if the list is not empty. I think re.findall returns a list of string, so you don't have to use `str(result2[0])`

Comment: Try logging the string `etherPrice` in the case that the list ends up being empty.

Comment: If `result[0]` fails you simply have not `result[0]` which means result is empty. Probably your search patterns allows for non-hits.

Answer (score 0):

The list is empty, when the list is empty (`[]`) `list[0]` will throw an error.

```py
resultString2 = None # initialize the result to None, or "" 

etherPrice = str(cryptocompare.get_price('ETH', currency='USD'))
intRegex2 = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+')
result2 = intRegex2.findall(etherPrice)

# If the matches list is not empty, then retrieve the first element:
if (result2):        
    resultString2 = str(result2[0])
```

You can also use `if (len(result2) > 0)` but that's redundant.